# Check a renderText value in a conditionalPanel in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am doing a R Shiny web application.

I want to check a `RenderText` value with a `conditionalPanel` in the UI part. If the value equals "yes", a confirm sentance must appear.
My code is :

Server.R :

```
       output$TestConnected <- renderText({
       'yes'
   })
```

UI.R

```
  tabItem("admin", 
       conditionalPanel(condition="output.TestConnected =='yes'", HTML("Validation OK"))
  )
```

But the "Validation OK" sentence does not appear where it should.
Do you know how to manage to do it with the use of `conditionalPanel` ?

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have to remove the "," at the end of the line?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the comma has no impact and there still is an error at removing

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working shiny app code. As is it is just a snippet of an UI and a server code. Did you include something like a `textOutput("TestConnected")` in your UI?